# Counting unique (distinct) users per day

Tags: postgresql, count, distinct

I am new to`psql` and am interested in counting the **number of unique first time users per day**.

My table only has two columns- `user_id` (there can be multiple uses by one user per day) and `start_time` which is a timestamp that indicates the time of use. The count should only include users whose min(start_time) fell on that day.

Why does the following query not work? Shouldn't it be possible to select distinct on two variables at once?

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT min(start_time::date), user_id), 
       start_time::date as date 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY date
```

produces

> ERROR:  function `count(date, integer)` does not exist

The output would look like this

```
        date count
1 2017-11-22    56
2 2017-11-23    73
3 2017-11-24    13
4 2017-11-25    91
5 2017-11-26   107
6 2017-11-27    33...
```

Any suggestions about how to count distinct min Date and user_id and then group by date in psql would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't show data, so it's a bit hard to understand what you mean when you say "first time"? If a user visits a site on two distinct days, do they only get tallied once on the first day, or on every day they visit once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your form is off, what you want is

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT x)
FROM generate_series(1,10) AS gs(x);
```

Or, in your case,

```
SELECT start_time::date, count(DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY start_time::date;
```